# Android: Get DatagramSocket from a SocketFactory in JAVA

Tags: java, android, sockets

Is there way to get DatagramSocket from SocketFactory in android?

https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/SocketFactory.html

```
createSocket

added in API level 1
Socket createSocket (String host, 
                int port)
```

Above get the Socket which is TCP kinds.. Need a DatagramSocket UDP socket.

Is this possible?

**Use case:**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#getSocketFactory()

From Network.getSocketFactory get a DatagramSocket specifically.

Thanks

Nithin

Comment: Why? What's wrong with `new DatagramSocket(...)`?

Comment: @EJP see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#getSocketFactory()

Answer (score 0):

Starting with API level 22, you can use [`Network.bindSocket(DatagramSocket)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html#bindSocket(java.net.DatagramSocket))

> Binds the specified `DatagramSocket` to this `Network`. All data traffic on the socket will be sent on this `Network`, irrespective of any process-wide network binding set by `bindProcessToNetwork(Network)`. The socket must not be connected.